# App closes without error or stacktrace silently

Tags: flutter

My app consistently crashes at the same location. Should be easy to fix as I could trace the issue down to the exact location. But there is no error message at all. No break occur in debugger. It just crashes completely and silently. No stack, no actual error. App closes and that is it. Tried in 1.13 and 1.17.

> Lost connection to device.
>
> Exited (sigterm)

Any idea how to tackle? How to find such error? It is on iOS.

Comment: there must be a page where this happens, or it just crashes on start?

Comment: App runs fine until it reaches a line in the code. Where it simply closes.

Answer (score 0):

For those who meet a similar issue. Seems native iOS codes won't throw exception. A plugin with a bug may crash your app straight.